# Setting hidden field value with bootstrap radion button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am have some trouble with setting the value of a hiddenfield with a boostrap radio button. here is the button group with the radio buttons and the hiddenfield.

```
<div class="myRow">
                <div class="smallCol">
                    <div class="btn-group hiddenRFIDValue" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" class="btn" name="options" id="alwaysRFID" autocomplete="off">
                            Always
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" class="btn" name="options" id="neverRFID" autocomplete="off">
                            Never
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" class="btn" name="options" id="sometimesRFID" autocomplete="off">
                            Sometimes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenRFIDValue" runat="server" />
```

Here is the script that i am trying to set the value with.

```
<script>
    $(".hiddenRFIDValue .btn").click(function () {
        // whenever a button is clicked, set the hidden helper
        $("#hiddenRFIDValue").val($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

Hope one of you can help with it. Thanks

Comment: `$("#hiddenRFIDValue").val($(this).parent().text());`

Comment: @Tushar the value is still null for some reason when i put the parent() on there

Comment: Try `$("#hiddenRFIDValue").val($(this).closest('label.btn').text());`

Comment: @Tushar still null. What does the .closest('label') do?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Are you sure button click is triggering?

Comment: But your code is working fine. **[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/vd1huwkf/)**.. Check the console after `click`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Okay that seems to be the problem. The button i never beeing fired. But why is it not ? it says it is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! when the html is generated it changed the id of the hidden field so the scipt needed to look like this.

```
<script>
    $(".hiddenRFIDValue .btn").click(function () {
        $("#MainContent_hiddenRFIDValue").val($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```